# Time series data stores in CI context - meaning?

Tags: continuous-integration, terminology

From reading this [job ad](https://workday.wd5.myworkdayjobs.com/Workday/job/Ireland-Dublin/DevOps-Engineer---Syman-Search-Dublin_JR-18369):

> You believe CI servers, push button deploys, **time series data stores**,
>   metrics dashboards, and centralized logging are not just “nice to
>   haves” they are critical pieces of infrastructure that rapidly pay for
>   themselves.

What does using a [time series data store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_series_database) mean for CI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does using a time series data store mean for CI?

Nothing in the context of that job description.  CI and time series databases are separate entries in the list.  To put it another way:

```
infrastructure_pieces = [
    'CI servers',
    'push button deploys',
    'time series data stores',
    'metrics dashboards',
    'centralized logging',
]

for infrastructure_piece in infrastructure_pieces:
    assert(candidate.important_of(infrastructure_piece) == 'CRITICAL')
```

That is, the job involves maintaining CI, but it also involves monitoring production servers and applications using TSDBs, and various other activities.

Answer (score 1):

Since time series datastores are indexed by timestamps they can be very useful in a CI/CD environment, depending on what kind of information they store, for things like:

- incident analysis and management
- service operation and SLAs monitoring
- overall SDLC pipeline performance/efficiency analysis and improvements
- resource capacity planning
- budget and ROI computations